# pdf generation from xml or html

Tags: spring, pdf, itext

We have a requirement for generating a pdf of a html report we show on screen. Now this report will be stored in the db too as xml or pdf so it can be viewed in the future. 
So i am thinking of using itext to generate the pdf from the backend. But question is do we use the html to generate the report using htmllworker or do we use the xml from the server side to generate it. 
Using xml seems the better choice since its more reusable but xmlworker should be faster to code ?

Question is do u see any drawbacks in either case ? With xml-pdf we have to change in 2 places if any change is req on front end.
Any suggestions on which one. to use ?

Comment: Is the HTML report complicated? Does it contain many divs (nested or not with markup?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it would recommend using only one point of change, which would be the HTML. If you change the HTML only there are many tools that convert:

- wkhtmltopdf (webkit based, own install, CSS2 + some CSS3)
- dompdf (PHP CSS2.1 engine)
- an external API (several APIs out there e.g. [htm2pdf.co.uk](http://htm2pdf.co.uk))

By changing only the HTML you wouldn't have to worry about differences in the source (HTML) and the result (PDF) as much, but only make sure that the converter handles the things that you do well. Look out for your styling requirements and especially pagination.

Good luck